# AWS integration with Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am new to android development and is trying to implement aws sdk in my app. I read the developer documentation of aws but get confused as where to write the code that has been provided their in my android studio project.

Comment: see this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html  and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

Answer (score 2):

AWS recently launched the AWS Mobile Hub, which is an integrated console experience, designed to help people like you get started quickly. Mobile Hub configures your AWS resources and generates a sample Android mobile app project, which uses your resources. You can then use the sample app as a starting point for your own app, or just copy and paste the code you need. This is the fastest and simplest way to integrate with AWS. The sample app demonstrates use of the AWS SDK and gives some additional customized helper code that makes using the AWS SDK easier.

To give AWS Mobile Hub a try, simply go to:
http://aws.amazon.com/mobile